# web scraping odds from oddsportal

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to programming with Python 3.8.3.

I like football and I like to study the odds of various leagues. I'm trying to extrapolate the odds from the [oddsportal.com](https://www.oddsportal.com/) site which I would then like to transfer to excel.

My problems are two:

1. I can't understand how to extrapolate all the games in this way,
   without creating more codes each time (10 codes if there are 10
   games, 5 codes if there are 5 games, etc.) now there is my example
   about germany - Bundesliga - but I want to scrape more championships At
   the moment I can only **scrape** the first one match in the list. Is
   there a quick way to do it all?
2. I would like to bring these data in
   the form of a table on excel (maybe even with a comma as a decimal
   separator) and as regards the opening odds I am not interested in
   the movements .. I would only be interested in the opening odd and
   the current odd!

Here is my code:

```
import urllib
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import openpyxl

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe") #choose the webdriver location (chrome)
driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/germany/bundesliga/") # comics url

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tournamentTable"]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/a[2]').click()

print('Bookmaker', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/a[2]').text)
print('Match', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="col-content"]/h1').text)
print('Data', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="col-content"]/p[1]').text)
print('1', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]').text)
print('X', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]').text)
print('2', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]').text)
print("=========")
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a')

hover=ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)

hover.perform()

print('opening Odds Home[1]', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tooltipdiv"]').text)

element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a')

hover=ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)

hover.perform()


print('opening Odds Net[X]', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tooltipdiv"]').text)


element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/a')

hover=ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)

hover.perform()


print('opening Odds Away[2]', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tooltipdiv"]').text)
print("=========")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bettype-tabs"]/ul/li[8]/a/span').click()
time.sleep(1)
print('Doppia Chance', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/a[2]').text)
print('1X', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]').text)
print('12', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]').text)
print('X2', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]').text)
print("=========")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bettype-tabs"]/ul/li[5]/a/span').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[4]/div/span[5]/a').click()
time.sleep(1)
print('Over 1,5', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/a[2]').text)
print('Under/Over', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]').text)
print('Over 1,5', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]').text)
print('Under 1,5', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]').text)
print("=========")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[8]/div/span[5]/a').click()
time.sleep(1)
print('Over 2,5', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[8]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/a[2]').text)
print('Under/Over', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[8]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]').text)
print('Over 2,5', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[8]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]').text)
print('Under 2,5', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[8]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]').text)
print("=========")
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[8]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a')

hover=ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)

hover.perform()

print('opening Odds Over 2,5', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tooltipdiv"]').text)


element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[8]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/a')

hover=ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)

hover.perform()

print('opening Odds Under 2,5', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tooltipdiv"]').text)
print("=========")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[15]/div/span[5]/a').click()
time.sleep(1)
print('Over 3,5', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[15]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/a[2]').text)
print('Under/Over', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[15]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]').text)
print('Over 3,5', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[15]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]').text)
print('Under 3,5', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[15]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]').text)
print("=========")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tab-sport-others"]/span').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bettype-tabs"]/ul/li[14]/div/div/p/a[3]').click()
time.sleep(1)
print('Both Teams Scores', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/a[2]').text)
print('Goal', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]').text)
print('Nogoal', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]').text)
print("=========")
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a')

hover=ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)

hover.perform()

print('opening Odds Goal', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tooltipdiv"]').text)

element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a')

hover=ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)

hover.perform()

print('opening Odds NoGoal', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tooltipdiv"]').text)
```

Comment: what table are you actually after?

Comment: I need the odds of some championships to be able to use them on Excel.  I have a sheet in Excel where I make predictions using statistics and odds.  every time there is a game I manually enter the odds of: 1, X, 2, 1X, X2, 12, UNDER 1,5, OVER 1,5, UNDER 2,5, OVER 2,5, UNDER 3,  5, OVER 3.5, GOAL, NOGOAL and their respective opening odds.  what i would like to do is get an Excel grid with these dimensions a way to do a simple copy-paste, without having to do everything by hand.